# Correct Birthday format in MySQL for all users in Table

Tags: mysql

I made a mistake in last update of my code,

First time I'm asking users for Date format like **1999-05-21**

Then second time I changed format to **21-05-1999**

Now issue is script only work for 1999-05-21 (YYYY-MM-DD) format users, but there are lots of users who has registered with incorrect, How to correct all users birthday in MySQL database

Any way to reverse this sequence? On server or By exporting DB on local machine or any software?

Comment: You should store date as dates, not strings.

Comment: @Shadow I think old developer store as string because it can support different types of format like 10-12-1999 and 10-Dec-1999 and 1999-12-10 because of API uses

Comment: You seem to be saying that there are no rules at all for accepting date, if so then there is no simple way of doing this you have to test all known variations and manually change the oddities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse these as dates with `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Eg.

```
> SELECT (STR_TO_DATE("21-05-1999", "%d-%m-%Y"))
"1999-05-21"
```

That should allow you to update all the rows that parse to date with that format to correct dates

```
UPDATE birthdays SET birthday = STR_TO_DATE(birthday, "%d-%m-%Y")
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, "%d-%m-%Y") IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I used this command `UPDATE users SET birthday = STR_TO_DATE(birthday, "%Y-%m-%d") WHERE STR_TO_DATE(birthday, "%d-%m-%Y") IS NOT NULL;` but it replaces **26-05-1974** to **2026-05-19** any idea why?

Comment: You have changed  the format when setting the new birthday to `"%Y-%m-%d"` for some reason. That should be `"%d-%m-%Y"`, because that's the format you are parsing from.

Comment: This will not help if you already have mixed entries in your database

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users SET birthday = CONCAT(SUBSTR(birthday, 7, 4),'-',SUBSTR(birthday, 4, 2),'-',SUBSTR(birthday, 1,2) WHERE SUBSTR(birthday, 3,1) = '-'
```

and after that you should change the column format with

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY COLUMN birthday DATE
```